# Sum and chart in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have data like the following:
Both Hour and Count are columns in an excel file.

```
Hour    Count  
17  79  
18  122  
19  123  
20  142  
21  150  
22  78  
23  15  
13  33  
14  33  
15  40 
16  33
17  56
18  46
19  35
20  67
21  65
22  45
23  36
```

What I want is to create a chart that shows over a period of 1 to 24 (hours) the total count.  What's the easiest way to do this.

The chart should have a horizontal axis that runs from 1 to 24; and a vertical axis that goes from 0 on up.

In the case above the values should be combined like:

```
1 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 0
4 - 0
5 - 0
6 - 0
7 - 0
8 - 0
9 - 0
10 - 0
11 - 0
12 - 0
13 - 33
14 - 33
15 - 40
16 - 33
17 - 135
18 - 168
19 - 158
20 - 209
21 - 215
22 - 123
23 - 51
24 - 0
```

Comment: Where is hour 1?

Comment: Not there.  I'd like excel to chart a zero.

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot clearer. Where is the data, what do you want on your axes, etc

Comment: Do you mean by total that the hour 17 figures should be totalled together?  Can this be done beforehand by the data source?

Comment: @Paul: totalled together, can't be done before hand.

Comment: @soandos: does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Assuming the hour is in column A and the count is in column B.

In column D, put the numbers 1-24

In column E, put the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$18,CONCATENATE("=",D1),$B$1:$B$18)
```

This will product your second table above.

Then add a chart, and use $E$1:$E$24 as the data range, and $D$1:$D$24 for the categories.  In the image below I have ordered the original data, but it isn't necessary.

[image]